# Making a flash drive to a hard drive

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, removable

I've found [a tutorial here](http://www.getusb.info/usb-hack-turn-a-usb-stick-into-a-hard-drive-or-local-disk/) on how to trick the operating system to see a flash drive as a hard drive.

But I have a few questions:

- This trick will only work on the os wherein you updated the flash drive driver. Is there a trick that will work like this one, but if you plug in the flash drive to another computer it will still be treated as hard drive?
- How do I convert it back to a flash drive?

Comment: Why would you want to? surely at the end of the day your just putting data on a stick

Comment: yup but its easier to partition the flash drive its treated as hard drive.

Comment: Last time I checked, a flash drive *is* a hard drive..

Comment: I have a program that refuses to be installed in a flash drive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can partition a flash drive using `diskpart`. For more information read the [TechNet Diskpart Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28WS.10%29.aspx)

**Example:**

Run command prompt "As Administrator"

Run these commands in this order at the command prompt and replace # with your flash drives Disk # listed when you run list disk

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk #
clean
create partition primary size=1000
select partition 1
active
format fs=NTFS
assign
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

If/when you find Diskpart to be insufficient or useless, you will find joy using [RMPrepUSB](http://www.rmprepusb.com) - it's a free utility from the geniuses at reboot.pro.

Check this screenshot for an example:

> By adding a small, hidden second partition to the drive, some BIOSes will treat the drive as a hard disk and not a removable drive
>
> [image]

Comment: I couldn't get this working.

Answer (score 1):

The driver solution provided by OP is for 32 bit and won't work for the 64bit OS. One can also looks for USB with Lexar based firmware and used [this tool](http://www.getusb.info/flip-your-bit-usb-utility-to-make-local-drive/). The tool will flip  Removable Media Bit(RMB) setting of a USB drive. Corsair, a well known vendor, does not support this. See [the thread](http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?p=613350).